# Распознавание прав доступа в Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в Windows forms можно отличить обычный запуск программы от запуска с правами администратора?

Answer (score 1):

подключаем пространство имен

```
using System.Security.Principal;
```

и определяем, от администратора ли была запущена твоя программа

```
WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
bool isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```